# Understanding code splitting on facebook.com

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, webpack, code-splitting

I was going through [this](https://engineering.fb.com/2020/05/08/web/facebook-redesign/) post regarding how Facebook redesigned its homepage. It talks about code splitting and loading code in three tiers for fast first paint.

The first bundle loads the "skeleton" of the page to indicate loading of data:
[image: loading state]

The second bundle loads all the "above the fold content" at once:
[image: content loaded]

Third bundle contains code for the rest of the page.

Considering that Facebook used React to build their new webpage, I would like to understand how the code in bundle-2 interacts with the code in bundle-1?

What I mean is, that once bundle-2, along with its data is loaded, the "UI skeletons" are replaced by actual components with complete data at the *same* place. That means in React code, we will have to either:

1. place the skeleton components besides other "content" components, or
2. we can replace the root of all skeleton component with the 'content' component.

When I loaded the page over a slow connection, I could see that some skeleton components were not replaced by content components after load. This means either they duplicated skeleton components in bundle-2 (corresponding to case 2 from above), or they somehow managed to load all 'content' components *besides* skeleton components by discarding the corresponding skeleton components (this corresponds to case 1 from above). If this is the case, how could they be managing this in React (at code level)?

Comment: We'll likely never know exactly what Facebook does (unless they shared publicly, which I'm unaware of), but it's probably done automatically with stuff like [dynamic imports, `lazy` and `suspense`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html).

Comment: @EmileBergeron:  dynamic imports, lazy and suspense are just ways of importing code, ie. they dictate *how* the code will load, but not where it will be *placed*. My question is regarding the latter.

Comment: The _where_ it'll be placed depends on the bundler you chose to use. E.g. Webpack will transpile the code (change the paths, make different bundles, etc.) and merge the bundles as they're loaded. It looks like Facebook made their own plugin to transpile specific components in specific bundles that are just made available when the promise resolves.

Comment: Webpack runs on build time, not run time. so it's not possible for Webpack to pick components from bundle-1 and merge them into bundle-2 after bundle-2 has been loaded in the browser. Also, it doesn't seem like they loaded all components dynamically via something like suspense, because that would mean a separate ajax call for each component. But FB is loading all these 'content components' in one single bundle (bundle-2), and not separately.

Comment: [Webpack can definitely prepare different bundles at build time that gets merged at runtime](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/) so that it's entirely transparent when used either synchronously (normal `import ... from`) or async (lazy, suspense, `import()`, etc). Facebook did their own plugin to ensure which bundles gets which components and that only 3 bundles are fetched in a specific sequence, but that part is proprietary, apparently, as they only gloss over the pseudo syntax as an example (e.g. `importForDisplay`).

Comment: Even if they are somehow able to merge all dynamic imports into one bundle, how does the code from bundle-1 refer code from bundle-2, given that bundles are self-isolated packs of code which doesn't expose any globals?

Comment: Who said nothing was exposed globally? Quickly looking at a production site built with webpack, I see [`webpackJsonP` on the `window` object](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-changes-part-1-week-24-25-fd4d77674e55).